# Data Structure for files generated by GAMUT (Gambit file format)

Tags: data-structures, game-theory

GAMBIT file has the inputs for a n-player strategic form game. It consists of payoff values for each player's strategy. In order to do manipulations on the data, the data needs to be stored in some data structure efficiently.

Since the number of players and the number of actions are user-inputs, this is posing a bit of a problem. I am not able to come up with a better data structure than linear array to store the data. Any help is appreciated.

The code needs to be in C/C++/Java. So any suggestions on doing it in MATLAB or other software won't be helpful.

For those who needs to know about GAMUT and GAMBIT, refer
http://gamut.stanford.edu/download.htm

Thanks.

Comment: Define what you mean by "efficiently". Do you want to minimize file size? Make the file easy to read by other programs? Why is a flat file not good enough?

Comment: @JoseMVidal By efficiently, I mean to group data that will ease accessing the payoff values. I don't understand what you mean by flat file. You have raw data from the GAMBIT file, you have to process it to get information.

Comment: I think GAMUT has datastructures implemented and it uses the appropriate ones for efficient representation when the user generates a game. e.g. in Graphical Games, the game can be represented efficiently by a graph. In case of graphs, the user has a few choices on which graph he will use (I'm still trying to figure out how these graphs work myself, though.) As an example, in polymatrix games, input can be represented polynomially as opposed to exponentially when one makes use of Graph datastructure. GAMUT is able to parse a game to GAMBIT input (.nfg files)

Comment: If you still desire an answer, I can post a code example that generates a simple game and writes it to a .nfg which can be used as gambit input?